# I can not reinstall ESET Smart security in my Windows Server

Tags: installation, firewall, windows-server-2008-r2

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 (remote access - can not use safe mode) and during installation of Eset Smart Security 4 server hanged and after that I reset server.

so I want to uninstall bad installation of that eset and reinstall it!
but there is no eset in uninstall programs area and or in msconfig startup!
so I tried to reinstall eset without removing previous ver, but during installation I have an error about registry keys.
so I tried to delete all registry keys about eset, but I got the error below :

> can not delete this key

I ran `regedit` as an administrator -> but did not help.

how can I fix that?

Comment: some body help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Eset uninstaller. [Here is the KB](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2289) from their site. I realize you can't boot into safe mode but as far as I can tell this is just so the ESET service doesn't lock any of the files that need to be deleted as in use. Check services.msc and see if it got far enough to actually install as a service, if not you should be fine running the uninstaller outside of safe mode (if not it will tell you immediately and leave an error file on your desktop). You can also try a selective boot from msconfig (just make sure you keep remote desktop services and networking enabled). As a side note did you attempt this installation from an ERAS (Eset Remote Administration Server)? If so make sure the ERAS service on your remote admin server is running as your domain admin and not as a local service (this sometimes helps with installs on 2008).